# Surjectivity of the Laplacian $\Delta:W_0^{k+2,p}(M)\to W^{k,p}(M)$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with nontrivial boundary. I'd like to show that for each nonnegative integer $k$ and every $p>1$, the $g$-Laplacian
$$\Delta:W_0^{k+2,p}(M)\to W^{k,p}(M)$$
is surjective. $W_0^{k+2,p}(M)$ is the collection of functions in the Sobolev space $W^{k+2,p}(M)$ that vanish on $\partial M$.

To begin the proof, let us choose any $f\in W^{k,p}$. Then there exists a sequence of functions $f_i\in C^\infty$ that converges to $f$ in $W^{k,p}$. Invoking the Poincaré inequality and the Lax-Milgram theorem, we can find $u_i\in C_0^\infty$ so that $\Delta u_i=f_i$. Again, the subscript of $C_0^\infty$ signifies vanishing on $\partial M$. Now, with the help of the injectivity esitmate
$$\lVert u\rVert_{W^{k+2,p}}\ \ \leq C\lVert\Delta u\rVert_{W^{k,p}}\ ,$$
we can conclude that $u_i$'s form a Cauchy sequence in $W^{k+2,p}$, since $f_i$'s constitute a Cauchy sequence in $W^{k,p}$. Then the fact that $W^{k+2,p}$ is complete implies $u_i\to u\in W^{k+2,p}$. Now I'd like to propose **two questions**:

1. Can the limit $u$ be possibly in $W_0^{k+2,p}$?
2. Does $u$ solve $\Delta u=f$?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Note that $u_i\in C_0^\infty$ and $u_i\to u$ in $W^{k+2,p}$. Recall that $W_0^{k+2,p}$ is the completion of $C_0^\infty$ with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_{W^{k+2,p}}$. So $u$ is in $W_0^{k+2,p}$.

Comment: For the second question: for any test function $\psi\in C_0^\infty$, we have $\int u_i\Delta \psi=\int f_i \psi$ for all $i$; taking limit in $i$ gives that $\Delta u=f$ in the weak sense (the limitation process only uses that $u_i\to u$ in L^p$.)

Comment: @Feng I frequently come across the statement "the completion of the space ... in the norm ..." but know nothing about it. Could you explain how it really works? Thank you very much.

Comment: OK. If $X$ is a normed vector space with norm $\|\cdot\|_X$, then by Functional analysis result, there exsits a completion of $X$, i.e., there exists a complete normed vector sapce $Y$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_Y$ such that $X\subset Y$ and $\|x\|_X=\|x\|_Y$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: In the case here, $X=C_0^\infty$, the norm on $X$ is $\|\cdot\|_{W^{k+2,p}}$, then we can do the completion. Since $X\subset W^{k+2,p}$, and $W^{k+2,p}$ is complete, our completion of $X$ is a closed subspace of $W^{k+2,p}$, and we denote it by $W_0^{k+2,p}$.

Comment: To be more precise, here, $u\in W_0^{k+2,p}$ if and only if there exists a sequence of $u_i\in C_0^\infty$ such that $\|u_i-u\|_{W^{k+2,p}}\to0$. I hope that I have already explained everything clear.

Comment: @Feng I'm very sorry to have kept you waiting. Let us clarify the notation $X\subset Y$ in your definition of comletions. According to Munkres' book on Topology, there is an isometric embedding $h$ of $X$ in a complete metric space $(Y,D)$. Then the closure of $h(X)$ is a complete metric space in the relative metric induced by $D$, called the comletion of $X$. Is this what you were talking about? Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Yes! That is what I was talking about. But Munkre’s definition seems more abstract, so I just slacked off and required that $X\subset Y$, which is more easier to understand. Indeed, most “completions” we meet in PDE theories can be understood in the way I mentioned before.

Comment: @Feng 我後來發現第二個問題只需要$\Delta$的連續性即可，不管怎樣，謝了，中秋節快樂！